# FIGMA I con set that can quickly change Color

Tags: components, variance, figma

Trying to understand how to make component sets and use variance to make designing more simplified. I have a tile that has an icon on the right that I want to be able to change both what type of icon it is as well as its colour. Is there a way to create the two-component properties using variance? Do all the icons need to be grouped by color and do I need to adjust their naming conventions (still not to sure how that works as well)h
[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a more efficient way to do this, by taking advantage of Color Styles. With this method, you only have to create your icons once, and no need for variants. Color Style swapping will handle that.

Create your icon components, but using a boring black color. Avoid creating variants of the icons, if it's only the fill color that's changing.

Instead [create a standard set of Color Styles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d01Ql9ZtVnk) for your icons.

Your designers then, could place an instance of a black icon from your library. Then use the [Selection Panel to replace the black color with one of your defined color styles](https://help.figma.com/hc/en-us/articles/360042553434-View-and-adjust-colors-in-a-mixed-selection).